# TSL 1.2 on Ruby v 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, tls1.2

I'm new here and I really need some help! :)
We have a system using Ruby version 1.8.7 and an API needs to use TLS 1.2 certificate. What do you think we could do? Without updating, would it be possible?

We tried what is described here: https://chris.heald.me/2018/upgrading-legacy-ruby/

unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 is museum grade at this point. You *must* stop using it. It hasn't been supported in a long, long time, official support was dropped in 2014. There used to be a company that ran extended support for it, but I think they ceased operations over 5 years ago. I know getting out of the 1.8.7 world is awfully fussy, but the more you kick this can down the road, the more trouble you'll be in later. The good news is once past 1.9 things are pretty stable as far as breaking changes go.

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your post. It should include your exact inputs, exact outputs, and detailed steps you took so that the problem can be reproduced by others. Statements like *it didn't work* are not diagnostically useful. It's possible the linked article can be made to work but we can't tell without your input. Otherwise this post is "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" which is [a standard reason for questions to be closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: What @tadman said upgrading is the best option for you and your consumers in every way (performance, stability, security, longevity, ...). Moving from 1.8.7 -> 1.9.X is a little painful but 1.9 -> 2.7.X is almost seemless (the jump to 3.X has a few hurdles of its own as well).

Comment: You are absolutely right. I apologize and I will try to expose the problems better!
Thanks for the observation

Comment: If you have an app or system stuck on 1.8.7 I feel for you, but you really need to get out of that place as soon as you can. At the time the switch happened there was a lot of friction as not every dependency was 1.9+ compatible, but those days are long past so any issues you encounter should have tried and tested solutions.

Comment: Folks, Thank you very much for the responses. I'll try to be more objective next time.
You are right Tadman and engineersmnky
, We will try to update the system as soon as possible.